# Symfony Form / FormBuilder: How to add an option or attribute to multiple form fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to add a stylesheet class attribute to most of the fields, but not all.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name_short', null, ['attr' => ['class' => 'rtl']] )
        ->add('name_long')
        ->add('profile_education')
        ->add('profile_work')
        ->add('profile_political')
        ->add('twitter')
        ->add('facebook')
        ->add('website')
    ;
}
```

Is there a simpler way than adding the attribute `['attr' => ['class' => 'rtl']]` to every field? Looking for something like looping the fields and setting the attribute after adding the field to the builder.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this and remembered that I recently found a way that works.
Basically iterating over all fields removing and re-adding them with merged options.
Take this example below.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name_short')
        ->add('name_long')
        ->add('profile_education')
        ->add('profile_work')
        ->add('profile_political')
        ->add('twitter')
        ->add('facebook')
        ->add('website')
    ;
    
    $commonOptions = array('attr' => array('class' => 'rtl'));
    
    foreach($builder->all() as $key => $field)
    {
        $options = $field->getOptions();
        $options = array_replace_recursive($options, $commonOptions);
        
        $builder->remove($key);
        $builder->add($key, get_class($field->getType()->getInnerType()), $options);
    }    
}
```

Edit: Updated to work with Symfony 3, 4, 5 & 6. Thanks @Massimiliano Arione

Comment: I've try your solution but getting "Could not load type [fieldName]".
It works though if I replace the last line with:
$builder->add($key, $field->getDataClass(), $options);

Comment: Tried with Symfony 3.4, I had to use `$builder->add($key, \get_class($field->getType()->getInnerType()), $options);` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do this while constructing the form. Simply hold the field names in an array. If you need to assign different field types, then use an associative array instead.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $fields = array('name_short', 'profile_education', 'profile_work', 'profile_political', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'website');

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $builder->add($fields, null, array('attr' => array('class' => 'rtl')));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that not the answer I was looking for. Is there no way to alter a field once its been added to the builder via add()?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way. You can dig yourself trough the form builder code, I didn't found a solution.